# What happens to arguments pushed on the stack when a function call returns?

Tags: c, assembly, stack

Assume this C code:

```
int add(int a, int b){
 int c = a+b;
 return c;
}

int main(){
  int c = add(3,4);
  printf("%d", c);
  return 0;
}
```

When calling `add` the following happens:

```
Push 4 on the stack
Push 3 on the stack
Push the address of `printf` on the stack (return address)
call `add`
// do stuff under add
pop the stack and and goto `printf`
```

But values 4 and 3 under `add` are still on the stack `-0x18(%rbp)`. Are they not supposed to be cleared?

```
00000000000005fa <add>:
 5fa:   55                      push   %rbp
 5fb:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 5fe:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
 601:   89 75 e8                mov    %esi,-0x18(%rbp)
 604:   8b 55 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%edx
 607:   8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax
 60a:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 60c:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
 60f:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
 612:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 613:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000614 <main>:
 614:   55                      push   %rbp
 615:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 618:   be 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%esi
 61d:   bf 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%edi
 622:   e8 d3 ff ff ff          callq  5fa <add>
 627:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 628:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: 4 and 3 are put in registers ESI and EDI, not the stack.

Comment: Look under <add>

Comment: Ah, you mean the code of `add()` itself, not the code in `main()` that calls it.

Comment: Why do you think they will be cleared? There is no standard or even convention that requires that. An implementation certainly could do that but most don't as that would be costly.

Comment: I can't figuere "add" out, where is SP lowered below the local variables?

Comment: @Jasen, the compiler is taking advantage of the “red zone”. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)

Comment: @prl - The OS isn't specified, and Windows does not have a "red zone".

Comment: @rcgldr, do you have another explanation for why the compiler-generated code accesses memory below the stack pointer? Also, Windows compilers don’t pass parameters in RDI and RSI.

Comment: @prl - Yes, Windows doesn't pass parameters in RDI and RSI, but the OP and others reading this may not be aware of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But values 4 and 3 under add are still on the stack

Not really, because stack no longer covers the memory where `4` and `3` are stored. They are in the memory beyond the stack pointer. Although the values are still in the place in memory that used to be part of stack, they are now part of uninitialized garbage. Accessing them after the stack has moved on, e.g. by storing their addresses, would be undefined behavior.

> Are they not supposed to be cleared?

No, clearing these values is unnecessary, and could impact run-time efficiency of the program.

Comment: ahh i see, so since ESP isn't even incremented, that region of memory belonging to 3 and 4 are just a one time use and will be overwritten the next time stack is used.

Comment: I like to add a side question, does "pop rbp" increment the stack pointer?

Comment: @Josh Right, that's exactly what's going to happen the next time the stack space is needed.

Comment: @Josh Yes, pop operation moves the stack pointer in the direction opposite to push. The actual direction depends on the architecture: on some systems push is an increment, while on other systems it's a decrement.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `pop` instruction, the value at the top of the stack is stored in the specified register and the SP (stack pointer) register is incremented (on x86 the stack grows down).  It does NOT modify the memory location that was previously the top of the stack as there's no need to do so.

Whatever value was at the top of the stack will remain there until a new value is pushed on top of it.